# Tensorflow: Not restoring but only saving trainable variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Let's say I have a model with Y layers.

I am trying to restore the model with setting Y-1 layers to `trainable=False`, so I insert all Y-1 layers(variable names) into var_list when defining `tf.train.Saver(var_list=list_of_Y-1_layers)` so they can be restored.

I would like to not restore the last layer, which I would like to train myself, so if I put it var_list it gets restored and if I don't put it there, it doesn't save inside the checkpoint during training.

Does this variable gets saved elsewhere ? Or am I doing something wrong for saving/restoring?

Side note:
To check if a trainable variable is saved or not, I use the function `inspect_checkpoint()`, which is defined in `tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py`

Comment: So your issue is that you want to checkpoint the variable during training but also to avoid restoring it when you don't want to? One option is to save and restore everything but also have an op `init_trainable = tf.variables_initializer(tf.trainable_variables())` that you run after restoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two objects, one for saving, the other for restoring:

```
#used to restore:
saver_restore = tf.train.Saver(var_list=list_of_Y-1_layers)
#used to save, will save all variables
saver_save = tf.train.Saver()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your entire model without specifying a `var_list`. This will save all of the variables in a checkpoint. Then when you restore, you can specify `var_list` to the restore Saver to only restore your desired subset of layers.

Sources:

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#choosing_which_variables_to_save_and_restore